# Backreferences using OR

Tags: php, regex

I was trying to match the first and last letters in a few words that may be found in a string.  I was using a regex with `|`.

Let's take the following string:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

I want to match either `fox` or `dog`, so I made the following regex:

```
/fox|dog/
```

Using PHP's `preg_replace`, that regex works correctly:

```
$str = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
echo preg_replace('/fox|dog/', '=>$0<=', $str);
```

This echos:

```
The quick brown =>fox<= jumps over the lazy =>dog<=
```

That's not quite the result I want.  So, starting with that regex, I tried to modify it so that the result would look like this:

```
The quick brown =>f...x<= jumps over the lazy =>d...g<=
```

I tried with this code:

```
$str = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
echo preg_replace('/(f)o(x)|(d)o(g)/', '=>$1...$2<=', $str);
```

This did not produce what I wanted.  This echoed:

```
The quick brown =>f...x<= jumps over the lazy =>...<=
```

After some debugging, I figured out why.  I figured that since I was using `|` it would match each word separately, but it does not.  The `f` is backreference `1` as I thought, but the `d` is not.  The `d` is actually backreference `3`!  This is because the groups are for the entire regex, not just which side of the `|` is matched.  But, backreference `0` is *always* the word matched (`fox` or `dog`), so I'm a little confused.

How can I use back references to match the 1st and last letters of multiple words?

I found a solution using `preg_replace_callback`, but I was wondering if I could get this same result using backreferences.

```
$str = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
echo preg_replace_callback('/fox|dog/', function($matches){
    $a = $matches[0];
    return '=>'.$a[0].'...'.$a[strlen($a)-1].'<=';
}, $str);
```

Comment: I wish every question looked like this...

Comment: I also tried to achieve this just while ago... :)

Comment: I think the solution using callback function is much more powerful than using lookaround. You can even adjust the length based on the length of the match.

Comment: @nhahtdh: I agree.  The *correct* solution here is the callback method.  I was just wondering why the backreferences weren't working, and if it's even possible to do this with backreferences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually callback function method is superior to all this, since can work in all cases. You can even show more or less character depending on the length of the match.

---

**Below is my initial answer, which is inferior to what I described above**

In general, you can do it like this:

```
/(?=(.))(?:pattern)(?<=(.))/s
```

Fill in `pattern` with your pattern. I used `s` flag to make `.` truly matches any character without exception. The `pattern` needs not be inside *non-capturing group* if the original pattern doesn't have `|` on the highest level.

You still need to check the length of the text captured by pattern before doing the replacement, though. (Especially the case the length is 1, and possibly 2 also). This is easily achievable by using replace callback function.

However, note that the method above *may* not work well with pattern whose minimum length is 0.

Comment: +1, much superior than mine :-) You could make the pattern non-matching (with `(?:…)`), and I'm sure it's easy to make the pattern match only strings longer than 1 character - no need for callback.

Comment: @Bergi: Actually, no need to even modify the regex. Just use the callback function to process the matched text.

Comment: I agree that callbacks are better.  I was just curious if it was possible to use backreferences.

Comment: Am I doing something wrong here?  It doesn't seem like it's working right: http://ideone.com/N5hb1g

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Yes you are. You need to group `(?:fox|dog)` together, otherwise, it will match 2 pattern `(?=(.))fox` and `dog(?<=(.))`. Should have put that up as a warning.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Oh. Derp. I should've realized that's why it wasn't working.  Grouping the pattern makes it work great, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I could utilize a non-matching [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) expression for this:

```
/(?=fox|dog)(f|d)o(x|g)/
```

<sub>(didn't test in PHP, but works in JS)</sub>

It tests first whether the following is one of the searched words, and then matches first and last letter in only one capturing group. However, this method will get far more complicated if the words are not that similar (here: same length, same middle letter[s]).

Comment: It seems this could be modified for more words by using `.*?`.  This seemed to work fine: `/(?=fox|dog)(f|d).*?(x|g)/`

Comment: I like this, this is a clever way to use lookaheads :)

Comment: @Rocket: Yeah, for `.*?` you only need to care that words do not contain end characters of other words. `(?=foo|fox|dog)(f|d).*?(o|x|g)` wouldn't work, for example, it matches the `o` as last letter even for fox and dog. Therefore I like nhahtdh's solution with the lookbehind better…

Comment: I didn't think of that, but after testing, you're right.  I'm going with nhahtdh's solution too.  Thanks for this solution, though.  I didn't realize you could use lookaheads at the beginning of a regex like that.